# how to refresh page with post value

Tags: html, reload

I have page contain div (class=result)
so the div(result) contain another div (class=update)
div(update) contain insert form
when data inserted another page (succed.php) opend in div(update) and with $_POST['compet'] value
How Can I make the div(result) refresh after succed.php opened and recive $_POST['compet']
Hope it is Clear

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You cannot send a $_POST to a URL by page refresh unless you have already done so by form submit, and then approve it. The only other method involves an AJAX request override the window.onclose event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I soleved the problem  myself with ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready( function (){
         $.ajax({
      url: 'insert.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { compet: $('#compet').val() },
      success: function(data){
        $(".myresult").html(data);
      }
    })
    })
</script>
```